# WPF validation of input (on-the-fly) and unit test. Best practice for design

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, testing

I want to add a new form to an existing solution. The solution already has a Validator class, so I want to expand this class.

The Form I want to create contains a Textbox (for the input) and a Button. When the input is the correct format the submit button is enabled. The input must adhere to a certain regular expression: "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}$". I'm checking the input (on-the-fly) in the Form class like this:

```
private void inputTbx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SubmitButton.IsEnabled = Validator.IsInputValid(inputTbx.Text, RegexExpression);
}
```

I've put the regular expression as a variable in the Form class. I put it here because it is relevant to the textbox of this form only.

```
private const string RegexExpression = "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}$";
```

Here's the validation code:

```
public static bool IsInputValid(string inputToBeChecked, string regexExpression)
{
    if (inputToBeChecked == null || regexExpression == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var regex = new Regex(regexExpression, RegexOptions.None);
    return regex.IsMatch(inputToBeChecked);
}
```

So far so good. It seems to work fine. But I want to unit test it like so:

```
[TestCase("aZ13579")]
public void ValidateInputOkTest(string input)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(Validator.IsInputValid(input, RegexExpression));
}
```

But to do it like this I have to have a string in my ValidatorTest class similar to the Regular-expression used in the Form class. This doesn't seem like the right way to do it. What I really want to do is get the Regex expression from the form class, so I am sure it's the correct Regex-expression that I'm using. Otherwise the Regex-expressions could easily get out of sync.

**Here are the questions:**
What is best practice here? 
How do I get to this expression? I've tried doing it using Reflection, but I get a Threadstat error because it's a GUI component. Should I move the Regular-expression? If so where to?
I'm thinking there must be a smart way to do this. A smart design perhaps. Suggestions and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to want to back up a step and start to research the 'MVVM' design pattern.  When you hear people talk about putting no code in the code behind, testing like this is one of the big benefits (among many others).

MVVM is too big a topic to handle in a simple answer like this.  I'd search around on the web, and I'm sure other people have some good tutorials.

Just to be clear, it can be a big learning curve, but it's totally worth it.  MVVM is what makes WPF much much (MUCH) better than WinForms, rather than merely different.

Just to address your question a little more specifically, you won't be testing a GUI object like a Window or UserControl.  You'll be testing a view model which is just a regular class.

Here's a simplified version of what you might see

```
public class MyScreenViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private const string RegexExpression = "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}$"; 

  public bool UserInputIsValid { get { stuff; } set { stuff; }}
  public string UserInput { get { stuff; } set { stuff; ValidateUserInput();} }

  private void ValidateUserInput()
  {
    if (UserInput == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var regex = new Regex(RegexExpression, RegexOptions.None);
    UserInputIsValid = regex.IsMatch(UserInput);
  }
}
```

A view model in MVVM is the real logic of your screen.  It will expose simple properties that the view can bind to for display/input, but the view isn't necessary for testing the logic.

Then your test looks something like:

```
[TestCase("aZ13579")]
public void ValidateInputOkTest()
{
  var vm = new MyScreenViewModel();
  vm.UserInput = "SomeValidText";

  Assert.IsTrue(vm.UserInputIsValid);
}

[TestCase("aZ13580")]
public void ValidateInputNotOkTest()
{
  var vm = new MyScreenViewModel();
  vm.UserInput = "SomeInvalidText";

  Assert.IsFalse(vm.UserInputIsValid);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I realize among other things that it is bad practice to the codebehind files. So it's back to the drawing board :-/

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say 'bad practice'.  If you're not intending to write the code in the MVVM pattern than what you're doing is perfectly fine.  I would just suggest that in the long run you'd be better off going through the process of learning that pattern.  Most people end up thinking it's a much more productive pattern.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I ended up setting the Regex expression as a public property in the Validator class and keeping the validation code  in the codebehind. This way the Regex-expression is reachable from both production and the test code.
With regards to the MVVM pattern I will try to study it further. Would you happen to have a pointer to a good place to start? :-)

Comment: Josh Smith's book is extremely well regarded:  http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/